# Find 'all' files in a directory, not all files found

Tags: python, file, shell, scripting, find

Using python, I'm trying to find all files in /sys and match a certain file. The problem I'm having is that not all files are being found. It's not a matter of access. I know that python can read and write to the file, which I've tested manually using `file.open("file_path","w")` and `file.write()`. I just want to know whether there is some trick to locating files I'm missing here:

```
import os,re

for roots,dirs,files in os.walk('/sys'):
  match=re.search(r'\S+/rq_affinity',roots)
  if match:
    print(match.group())
```

I've already tried writing every single file found using `os.walk()` to a file and then using the shell and `grep` to see if the file I'm looking for is there, so the problem isn't with matching.

---

FIXED search:

```
import os,re

for roots,dirs,files in os.walk('/sys'):
  for file in files:
    match=re.search(r'\S+/rq_affinity',os.path.join(roots,file))
    if match:
      print(match.group())
```

Answer (score 2):

`rq_affinity` is a file isn't it? Why would you get that in `roots`?

Also the entries under `/sys/dev/block` are symlinks so you need to tell `os.walk` to follow them with `followlinks=True`.

Comment: That gets me a little bit further, but I still can't find all the files in a test directory like (/sys/devices/virtual/block/loop0/queue). EDIT: Nvm, I got it, forgot to look in the "files" list. Thanks man.